# Correct database? Does it need altering?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm creating a page where I want users to be able to book a seat for an event.

---

- 1 user can only book 1 seat
- users have no seat selected upon login, first after buying into a spot
- Need to able to clear seats table, without loosing anything from user-table (except of course the assigned seats.)

---

I've created two tables, and since I'm pretty new to mySQL, I wanted to check if this was done correctly:

- members-table:
- user_id  int(8)  Not null  auto_increment
- user_name varchar(30) Not null
- user_pass varchar(255) Not null
- seat_ID smallint(6) Yes NULL

---

- seats-table
- seat_ID smallint(6) No auto_increment
- user_id smallint(6) Yes NULL
- seat_status tinyint(4) Yes NULL
- seat_status tinyint(4) Yes NULL

---

I've created 2 FK-refs:

```
ALTER TABLE seats
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_seats  
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES members(user_id)  
ON UPDATE CASCADE  
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE seats
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_seats  
FOREIGN KEY (seat_ID) REFERENCES members(seat_ID)  
ON UPDATE CASCADE  
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Am I on the right track? Will I be able to progress to a decent final product with this setup? suggestions/improvements? I don't want to start all over in a couple of weeks because the database structure is of poor quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't see why you're using a second table if any user can only hold one seat at any given time, secondly `user_id` in `seats-table` should be the same size as `user_id` in members table namely `int(8)`, otherwise you won't be able to seat users after a while, third issue is the duplication of seat_status, I suppose that was a mistake or you had another name for it.
In my opinion a better idea is to use a single table if it's a 1->1 mapping and define it as

```
CREATE TABLE `members-table` (
   user_id int(8) not null auto_increment,
   user_name varchar(30) not null,
   user_pass varchar(255) not null,
   seat -- your type choice, should be nullable if not seated
);
```

Clearing the seats with this config would be as simple as

```
UPDATE `members-table` SET `seat` = NULL;
```

Comment: Also I don't see why you have 2 relationships between the 2 tables, one should be enough.

Comment: Would I be able to assign seat_status (whether it's vacant or not) to a 1 table design?

Comment: If seat_status should just be if it's vacant or not you don't need to use a separate variable for it, for example if seat is `varchar(3)` to allow for seat numbering like `A0` to `F20` you could use that to get occupied seats like this `SELECT seat FROM members-table WHERE seat IS NOT NULL`, and check whether a seat is vacant or occupied using `SELECT COUNT(seat) FROM members-table WHERE seat='C21'` - C21 is just an example here but this would result in 1 if seat is occupied and 0 if seat is free for the taking, also don't forget to set a `UNIQUE` constraint on the seat column

Comment: Of course your final design should depend on what you plan to do with those seats and how they are organized, you could also use a 2 table design, if you have a configuration which would make it very hard to find a vacant seat with this setup, if that's what you want let me know and I'll write it in a separate answer. The above configuration is easily usable only for seats organized just by number or by row and column where the row count and column count is fixed and you have no missing seats in the matrix

Comment: Lets pretend I'm an idiot, shouldn't be that hard - Please elaborate.
-------
Couldn't fx. create seats as int(5) and first 2 numbers is row, next 2 is columm, and the last number describes vacancy?

Comment: You don't need a number for vacancy, that is unless the seat can be in more than just the normal 2 states of vacant of occupied.

Comment: Define `seats unsigned int(4) null`
Find out the state of a seat `SELECT COUNT(seat) AS occupied FROM members-table WHERE seat=:SEAT` - replace :SEAT with the actual seat
I just realized finding an empty seat with this is quite complicated since mysql won't allow you to generate a number series dynamically posting alternate solution instead

Comment: You don't need the alternate solution if you don't want the find first free seat thingy (if for example you iterate anyway over all the seats to display them to the user and he chooses where he wants to be seated)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `seats` (
   id int(4) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
   row int(2) unsigned not null,
   col int(2) unsigned not null,
   UNIQUE(row, col)
) ENGINE InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `members` (
   user_id int(8) not null auto_increment primary key,
   user_name varchar(30) not null,
   user_pass varchar(255) not null,
   seat int(4) unsigned null,
   FOREIGN KEY(seat) references seats(id) on delete set null on update restrict,
   UNIQUE(seat)
) ENGINE InnoDB;
```

You will have to populate the seats database with all available rows and columns, use null on id when inserting to use the auto_increment feature!

Check if a seat is taken

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS occupied FROM members WHERE seat = (SELECT id FROM seats WHERE row = :ROW AND col = :COL);
```

Alternatively use `SELECT (1 - COUNT(*)) AS vacant` in the query above if it's more conveninent for you.

Find first free seat

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM seats WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT seat FROM members WHERE seat = seats.id);
```

Unassign all taken seats

```
UPDATE members SET seat = NULL;
```

Comment: Ah, and don't delete values from seats, ever, just set them null in members when they become vacant. Also engine InnoDB is mandatory if you want the foreign key constraint to work.